# Changing ODBC connection servername parameter using PowerShell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, odbc, connection-string

I need an automatic way to change only `servername` parameter of a connection to a PostgreSQL database.

The only way I found in my research is through a PowerShell script following instructions from this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771023.aspx). It states that `Set-OdbcDsn` can modify, add or delete connection properties.

I have the following script:

```
$DsnArray = Get-OdbcDsn -DriverName "PostgreSQL ANSI" |
            Where-Object {($_.Attribute["Servername"] -eq "oldServer")}
Set-OdbcDsn -InputObject $DsnArray -SetPropertyValue "Servername=newServer"
```

My problem is that the script is changing indeed the `servername` parameter, but deletes `Port`, `Username`, `Database`, `SSlMode`, `Description` parameters and I need them to remain as they are because they differ to each connection.

What am I missing in the commands? If you know a different way to achieve the same purpose of automatically modify existing connection strings, please let me know.